# How to record a video stream VLCJ

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, streaming

I want to record an rtp stream which is coming to my vlcj Java project to the local disk as mp4. I have done many research on the internet but the solutions are all about saving the whole stream to a file. But I want to save a specific part of stream. How can I do that?

```
player.media().play(mrl, options);
```

Also, is there a documentation for options argument for play method?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to play the portion that you want:

```
mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, ":start-time=30", ":stop-time=60");
```

You can add `:sout…` to save the portion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to play the whole stream from start till end, but for example after 4 minutes from playing the stream, I want to start recording and after some time I want to finish recording while playing stream continues. How can I do that?